# Fixed point converstion; understanding the to_sfixed(x,y,z) vhdl functon in the ieee_proposed library

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus, ieee

I'm looking at some code containing the following line:

```
a <= to_sfixed (-3.125, 7, -6);
```

**What is in `a` after this line has been run?**

I think I've found the function in `float_pkg_c.vhd`, this appears to be a key part of the code:

```
result_big := to_sfixed (
  arg         => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(rsigned),
  left_index  => left_index,
  right_index => (right_index-3));
result := resize (arg            => result_big,
                  left_index     => left_index,
                  right_index    => right_index,
                  round_style    => round_style,
                  overflow_style => overflow_style);
```

I've read [the guidance](http://web.archive.org/web/20160305202256/http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/). From [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160305202256/http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Float_ug.pdf):

> To_sfixed – “float” to “sfixed”. Inputs: arg (float), left_index and
>   right_index (natural) OR size_res  (ufixed). Parameters round_style :
>   Boolean (true), overflow_style : Boolean (true), check_error : Boolean
>   (true), and denormalize : Boolean (true).

However, I still haven't worked out the expected bits - Am I right to be expecting 13bits in total?

**Is there a simple way of answering such questions (e.g. with a command line interface) for myself?**

Comment: Your first parameter is a real.  You will find the overloading for that function in fixed_float_c.vhdl.  The range will be (7 downto -6) as a result, 14 bits.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex G  Guide to use of standard packages ,G.4 Using the fixed-point package and G.5 Using the floating-point package. There's also Peter Ashenden and Jim Lewis's book ***VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff*** 8.4 The Fixed-Point Math Packages and 8.5 The Floating-Point Math Packages for some simple examples.  An sfixed will have a two's complement integer part and a fraction part represented by the negative indexes of the sfixed array value. The 7, -6 define the precision (bounds) of the sfixed value returned.